# Seventh child of seventh child

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

A series of the seventh son of seventh son.

Father raises all 7 boys but the problem was there was a female next to the last and she is given up.  After the seventh boy is born mother divorces father.

Both parents are 7th children of 7th children but his family only recognizes males while mothers recognizes both.

Anyway daughter gets accepted to a magic college and is assigned a room in a house that is run by a ghost who used to be a magician.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  You say it's a series; how many books?  Do you recall any of the covers?

Comment: I read it on Amazon kindle and there were either 3 or 4 books in the series.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/ThirteenthChild

Comment: Close but not quite and I was so excited.  Thank you.  I may need to read this now.

Comment: It's vaguely similar to [Gift of the Unmage](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1445828.Gift_of_the_Unmage), though I managed to find a copy and it differs in some details. For example the house where the protagonist _Thea_ stays is run by a retired mage not the ghost of a mage.

Comment: *Equal Rites*, Pratchett?

Comment: I checked out both Gift of the Unmage and Equal Rites but unfortunately neither one is the series I am looking for.  They both look interesting though and I will be adding them to my reading list so thank you very much for your suggestions.